# Can I somehow run multiple web modules that share the same library module with one SpringBootApplication?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm starting a Spring project that should be consisted of four main modules:

1. **Core module** - has service and repository layer (should represent a common library for other modules)
2. **Admin module** - should contain its own security configuration and endpoints (Controllers)
3. **Customer module** - should contain another security configuration and Controllers
4. ?**Web module** - contains the SpringBootApplication that should start both Admin and Customer module.

Is this possible or should I separate the project into two Spring Boot projects with a common library?
Can I maybe configure a build in which Admin and Customer modules are built as .war files and run it with SpringBootApplication in Web module?

Customer and Admin modules don't have to be on the same port. The only thing that's important is to run it in the same time.

Below is the structure of my current project.

```
/project-root
   -pom.xml (pom packaging defined; modules: core, web-admin, web-customer)
   /core 
     -src (contains service and repository classes)
     -pom.xml (jar packaging)
   /web-admin
     -src (contains controllers and security configuration for admin portal)
     -pom.xml (jar packaging for now; dependency on core)
   /web-customer
     -src (contains controllers and security configuration for customers)
     -pom.xml (jar for now; dependency on core)
   /web
     -src (should contain SpringBootApplication to run all the modules)
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. You would just have to pay attention to a couple of things:

1. You web module should include all the other modules as dependencies;
2. The SpringBootApplication class should be at the top-level package, otherwise you would have to play a bit with the `baseScanPackages` attribute;

E.g:

```html
   /core 
     com.example.app.core      <--- All the core classes would be on this package
   /web-admin
     com.example.app.admin     <--- All the admin classes would be on this package
   /web-customer
     com.example.app.customer  <--- All the customer classes would be on this package
   /web
     com.example.app           <--- The SpringBootApplication class should be at this level
```

> Can I maybe configure a build in which Admin and Customer modules are built as .war files and run it with SpringBootApplication in Web module?

You don't need to package the admin and customer module as `war` files, `jar` packaging is perfect.

> Customer and Admin modules don't have to be on the same port.

Is this a hard requirement? If yes, then you would be better of writing 2 different applications. Otherwise, all the API's can be accessed on the same port.

Comment: Well, I just forgot to add dependencies on the admin and customer modules in the main module with SpringBootApplication - thank you very much!